# Can I develop an Asp.net core MVC application using Entity Framework 6 (not Entity Framework core)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I want to use `ASP.NET Core` with my new project as I heard that it's faster. However, the project will use extensive database accessing feature of which some are not supported by `Entity Framework Core`. I want to know, is it possible to develop an `ASP.NET Core MVC` application using `Entity Framework 6` (not `Entity Framework Core`)?

Answer (score 6):

Based on the [documentation of ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6), it says:

> To use Entity Framework 6, your project has to compile against the
>   full .NET Framework, as Entity Framework 6 does not support .NET Core.
>   If you need cross-platform features you will need to upgrade to Entity
>   Framework Core.

Comment: Thank you! So it's possible to do that at the cost of losing portability.

Comment: Aye, you can read more on the documentation I shared. Happy Coding!

Comment: Yes, as long as you're targeting the full .NET Framework (not .NET Core), you can use any of the existing .NET libraries (or your own, or open source, etc) from your ASP.NET Core apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the speed of Net Core, you can put your Db Context class in another .Net Framework project and then add reference to that project from Net Core project.
By doing that, you can use EF 6 in Net core and also gain the speed of Net Core web project.
The drawback is you loss cross-platform features.