# How can I setup identity in Asp.Net Core 2.0 Target Framework 4.6.1 using Asp.Net.Identity and Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I am migrating my project implemented in `Asp.Net` to `Asp.Net Core 2.0 target framework 4.6.1`. I want to continue to use `EF6` and `Asp.Net.Identity` in `asp.net core` since the Identity Core and Entity Framework Core has major breaking changes.

I thoroughly went through various official documentations ([Core and EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6), [Identity in Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x#add-identityuser-poco-navigation-properties)), searched for similar (but not exact) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953977/can-i-develop-an-asp-net-core-mvc-application-using-entity-framework-6-not-enti) on stack, but I still feel stuck and unable to find a starting point.

Anyhow what I am able to implement till now is this:

- The web project (which has Startup.cs) is in core that targets 4.6.1 framework.
- The identity setups and context definition is in another assembly/project altogether which is a 4.6.1 class library.
- I am stuck at importing and registering my previous version's Identity and EF6 in Core Startup.cs which is of different version.

Is it even possible? I already have used many similar variants that I gathered during research but didn't help either: `AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStore<Context>()`

Comment: I suggest one more time review the current solution. Probably it is worth to migrate on the latest dotNet 2.0 and EF core and it will take less time that adaptation of Asp.Net.Identity (obsolete) to work with.Net core.

Comment: It is definitely easy to create a completely new app, but we want our old live app to migrate to newer ones; so recreating it again isn't good idea because we can't afford sudden twice changes (one of asp.net core and one of ef core) altogether (Time and resource complexity)..

Comment: I think the point is that you should go all or nothing. There's very little point in migrating over to ASP.NET Core, if you're still trying to use all your old ASP.NET MVC stuff. There's a reason that Microsoft didn't shelve MVC when they release Core. It's a totally different application development paradigm. You don't "upgrade" to Core. It requires a complete application rewrite.

Comment: Okay...I am getting it. But it isn't binary altogether, because there is Core 2.0, then there is core 2.0 targeting Framework 4.6.1, then there is one that targets standards - this all is making things little overwhelming. Can't I 'upgrade' my app to core T461 instead of 'rewriting' it in Core 2.0. Or still I am messing up?

Comment: While you can use old Entity Framework, I'm not sure you can use old identity, at least not easily, because while EF is not dependent on asp.net - identity not so.

Comment: I think that u should choose path like Yoda use to say: do or do not there is not try so if u want to stay on bride side of force u should switch to net core 2 (so new solution, new nuget packages, etc) if u want to be dark u can make some kind of hybrid but mixing targets will probably introduce issues maybe not during development but execution in non windows environment. My development team switched to net core 2 mvc + ef core and it looks not so bad. Productivity is so high but it mostly requires to findout right lines of code to plugin in this nice stack.

Comment: @KaranDesai I was looking for the same thing, but I was unable to find it.  However I created a template for myself that uses Asp.Net.Identity together with JwtSecurityToken.  It seems to be working, at least with the test calls. You can see my project here: https://github.com/jsucupira/asp-net-core-api-identity-template

Comment: If you want to migrate to ASP.NET Core 2, its meaningless to use ASP.NET Identity and EF6. You would have to use MVC Core, EF Core and Identity Core in order to use the full potential and intent of .NET Core 2. I would suggest you to stay back at this point. Some time later when EF Core and Identity Core are more stable, then migrate the application completely.

Comment: Okay based on all comments, I think I should completely migrate. But What exactly is the purpose of Asp.Net Core Targeting 4.6.1 when you cannot use it fully? Why Microsoft didn't release Core directly and why it targetted 4.6.1?

Comment: @JonathasSucupira will surely try your repository. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @KaranDesai you can target the old framework at the cost of losing cross platform functionality and also you will lose on the lightweight platform of .net core and instead be using the heavy .net framework.

Answer (score 1):

One of the breaking change I faced when I was migrating from .NET Core 1 to .NET Core 2 was the removal of the ability to use INT for the data type of the primary key.

I had to add this https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/patch/1.1.3/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.cs into my project in order for my older EF DB all with INT as PK to work in .NET Core 2.

Can you elaborate more on your issue?